# WordPress export tool featured images missing

Tags: wordpress

I transferred all my articles from my old blog to my new blog with the official WordPress import tool. All articles have been adopted and all pictures are in the media library. However, the featured images are missing, they are not assigned to the articles. The IDs of the articles have not changed.

any ideas?

Comment: That's a well-known issue with WordPress Importer, I will suggest running little mapping script to fix the thumbnails or use another plugin that will migrate the thumbnails as well.

Comment: Do you have any plugin or script recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I had this similar problem with wordpress export tool. I tried this plugin [Export Featured Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-featured-images/) and it still works, you can try that.

Comment: You can try this: Delete the custom post type previously imported without featured img (and empty trash).
Import the file generated by this plugin.
Re-import my [custom] posts.